# react-native-calendars moved 1 day forward

Tags: react-native, calendar, react-native-calendars

At the time of creating the post, it was Friday 30th. For some reason, my calendar displays this day as Saturday:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNVRM.png)

My Calendar code:

```
          <Calendar
            style={{width: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 10}}
            theme={{
              selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#00adf5',
              selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
              dotColor: '#00adf5',
            }}
            onDayPress={this.onDaySelect}
            markedDates={this.state.markedDates}
            markingType="single"
            minDate={minDate}
            maxDate={maxDate}
            disableAllTouchEventsForDisabledDays={true}
          />
```

Comment: that's strange. even your `Wednesday` is spelt incorrectly. did someone touch your code?

Comment: @kenmistry Nope. I'm working alone on this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this file location

```
react-native-calenders -> src -> calendar -> header -> index.js
```

and changed

```
let weekDaysNames = weekDayNames(this.props.firstDay);
to 
let weekDaysNames = weekDayNames(6);
```

**I have faced the same issue**

**I have resolved this issue from the above solution**

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023, if anyone uses WeekCalendar then go to

```
react-native-calenders -> src -> commons-> WeekDaysNames.js
```

and edit the file like Jaimin Patel had recommended